# powershell create new spweb

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

How can I create a new instance of SPWeb?

I don't want to use Get-SPWeb or New-SPWeb as I don't want to get an existing object, or create a new page.

I just want to create a SPWeb object and set it's GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite firm with PowerShell and SharePoint, but you can't simply create an `SPWeb` without supplying any information. This doesn't make sense at all.

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579.aspx)

New-SPWeb:

Creates a new site in an existing site collection.

```
New-SPWeb [-Url] <String> [-AddToQuickLaunch <SwitchParameter>] ...
```

where `Url` is a required parameter.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information - is this for mocking / testing purposes? It sounds like it is as the other answer explains that an SPWeb is just a representative description of something that must physically exist already. You cannot just create one without having the source exist.

If you want to create one for testing purposes, you should look at the Fakes framework that comes with Visual Studio 2012, or Pex/Moles for Visual Studio 2010. This tool will let you create mocked SPWeb instances, something that is actually quite difficult normally since they are sealed classes with no virtual methods.